# Store meat raw or cooked outside

Tags: food-safety, raw-meat, outdoor-cooking

In the outside world ...

Let us imagine that we have enough meat to make two stews. Is it best to split meat and cook one today and one tomorrow or cook both today and reheat tomorrow?

Either way, there is no fridge.

Comment: What's the temperature outside?  Basically, everything you need to know is in the linked duplicate.

Comment: If fuel is plentiful (firewood) you could also keep tomorrow's stew simmering, but it would take a lot of attention.  If you're buying meat, using tinned for the second day is an option. There are also ways of keeping things cold without a fridge - ranging from insulation+ice to evaporative cooling.While effective and with a long history, their lack of provable performance and reliability makes them hard to match with the strict regulatory guidelines that are the norm here.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood food safety. It cannot tell you what is "better" or "worse". It only provides enough information for a binary choice, "safe" or "unsafe".

Comment: @rumtscho rather than "safe" and "unsafe" I was more thinking "impossible to make safe" or "harder to make safe".

Comment: @stevemarvell this is also not part of food safety prescriptions. Once your food is unsafe, you cannot turn it back to safe.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of nomenclature knowledge @rumtscho What is the correct term to describe raw chicken?

Comment: Hi steve, I am not sure where our misunderstanding lies. There is no specific term for raw chicken. Both raw and cooked chicken are safe when kept in the fridge, and once they are removed from the fridge, they are automatically considered unsafe after 2 hours. You cannot get around that rule no matter in what order you cook, reheat, etc.

Comment: Gotcha @rumtscho So a chicken sandwich for a packed lunch or picnic is unsafe and a after two hours a sausage can't be casseroled after two hours and a nor can it be reheated after two hours. All chicken in whatever form is unsuitable for camping if you don't have a fridge. Clarified.